# A quick question about quicksort with strings in vectors (c++)

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, memory, quicksort

I'm struggling with this implementation of quicksort. I know it's silly, but I have no clue why this won't work, and I've spent hours on it now.

The idea is really basic; given a vector of strings, sort the strings in place. The problem that occurs when running, is strings going missing, and no sorting happening.

```cpp
    int partition(std::vector<std::string>& words, int low, int high) {
        std::string pivot = words[high];
        int i = low-1;

        for (int j = 0; j <= high; j++) {
            if (words[j] < pivot) {
                i++;
                words[i].swap(words[j]);
            }
        }
        words[i+1].swap(words[high]);
        return i+1;
    }

    void quicksort(std::vector<std::string>& words, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int part_idx = partition(words, low, high);
            quicksort(words, low, part_idx-1);
            quicksort(words, part_idx+1, high);
        }
    }
    
    void get_sorted(std::vector<std::string>& words, int n_elems) {
        quicksort(words, 0, n_elems);
    }
```

If someone would please take a quick (pun intended) look at my code and give me a hint, I'd be super happy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thank you. I agree that is a good idea after thinking it through, so I changed it to < instead of <=. Still doesn't come any closer to sorting, though.

Comment: if `n_elems` is number of elements in `words` then your code has undefined behavior for accessing out-of-bounds. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: btw the number of elements in `words` is `words.size()`, you should not keep track of the size seperately from the vector

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold *I have no clue why this won't work* -- How many words are you attempting to sort?  If it's more than 5 or 6, that's too much data to start with.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j <= high; j++)` looks very wrong. It should be `for (int j = low; j < high; j++)` and so is `pivot = words[high]` you should pick `pivot = words[low]` or anything else within the range.

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold *The problem that occurs when running, is strings going missing, and no sorting happening.* -- A few calls to `vector::at()` instead of using `[ ]` may have detected issues with going out-of-bounds (where you would have been greeted with a `std::out_of_range` exception, instead of your code "running" with wrong output).

Comment: Thank you everyone, I changed the code to use words.size() and followed @ALX23z tip on the for loop. Now everything runs smooth!